# Backup Isolated Storage as whole and recover

Tags: backup, windows-phone-7.1, restore, isolatedstorage

I am developing a Windows Phone 7.1 application. The app serializes objects to JSON and saves them to the **IsolatedStorageSettings** file.

The objects also have images that the user may capture with a camera. These images are saved to Isolated Storage as a jpeg file with the "Extensions.SaveJpeg" method. Images are referenced by a unique ID from the object JSON so they can be loaded from the storage with the object itself or loaded only when needed.

Now that I have this up and running, I would like to create a backup to SkyDrive functionality with recovery.

What I want to ask is how can I simply backup the Isolated Storage as whole, and recover as whole?

I've been thinking if there is a way to (1) generate a zip file containing the whole Isolated Storage, (2) upload that to SkyDrive, (3) downloading from SkyDrive and (4) unzipping it replacing any existing files in the storage.

The steps (2) and (3) I know how to do (instructions found easily by google). I can also do step (1) but with many lines of code. I am seeking for a simple solution to zip the whole storage and recover from it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Perst as the local database solution for your windows phone application.It can be imported or exported as xml which you can upload/download to/from SkyDrive or other cloud system.

Home page of Perst:http://www.mcobject.com/perst/

Comment: That would require me to change my code base and migrate existing users to use the db. However it's not impossible, I'm not saying that this is not a potential solution.

How does Perst handle Bitmapimages?

Comment: Hi @wpcode8345,Perst is a OO Database,you can storge anything you want.

Comment: Ah, but its GPLv3 so I would have to release my source code also and from the whole program, not just the database part... There is a commercial license available yes but it's too expensive for my project which has limited customer base.